# Break flatMap after first Some occurence

Tags: scala, collections

```
abstract class Node(id: Long, name: String) {
  def find(id: Long) = if (this.id == id) Some(this) else None
}
case class Contact(id: Long, name: String, phone: String) extends Node(id, name)
case class Group(id: Long, name: String, entries: Node*) extends Node(id, name) {
  override def find(id: Long): Option[Node] = {
    super.find(id) orElse entries.flatMap(e => e.find(id)).headOption
  }
}
val tree =
  Group(0, "Root"
      , Group(10, "Shop", Contact(11, "Alice", "312"))
      , Group(20, "Workshop"
          , Group(30, "Tyres", Contact(31, "Bob", "315"), Contact(32, "Greg", "319"))
          , Contact(33, "Mary", "302"))
      , Contact(1, "John", "317"))
println(tree.find(32))
```

Tree data is built from *Contact*s and *Group*s (w/ sub-Groups and Contacts). I want to find a node with specific *id*. Currently I traverse *Group*'s members using:

```
entries.flatMap(e => e.find(id)).headOption
```

but it isn't optimal because I check all child entries instead of break upon first finding.

I'd appreciate your help in magic *Scala Wold*. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `collectFirst`, which will select the first matching element and wrap it in `Some`, or `None` if it's not found. You can also turn `entries` into a view, to make the evaluation lazy.

```
entries.view.map(_.find(id)).collectFirst { case Some(node) => node }
```

It will work with your original code, as well:

```
entries.view.flatMap(_.find(id)).headOption
```

Comment: Hi, but it will return (20, "Workshop") node - first child of a *"Root"* which contains *id==32* in its sub-tree. I want *tree.find(32)* to return *(32, "Mary")* node.

Comment: You're right. `collectFirst` actually fails because of the nature of the search. So I'd stick with the `view`. Also, I think you mean that it should return `(32, "Greg")`. Normally `collectFirst` would work much better for this sort of thing, but since each `Node`, calls `find` again for each of its children, it causes the found element to be the top level one, and not the bottom, which we don't want.

Comment: Thank you [m-z](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2292812/m-z). Both ways work well, *flatMap-headOption* variant is shorter but *collectFirst* is easier to understand, at least for me - less *~magic~* involved(but I'll keep *flatMap* in comment). Once again - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach this problem could be providing traverse support for the data structure. Overall it's a tree so it can be traversed easily. Please check the code below:

```
sealed abstract class Node(val id: Long, val name: String) extends Traversable[Node] {
  def foreach[U](f:Node => U) = this match {
    case x: Contact => f(x)
    case x: Group => f(x); x.entries.foreach(_ foreach f)
  }
}
case class Contact(override val id: Long, override val name: String, phone: String) extends Node(id, name) {
  override def toString = (id, name, phone).toString
}
case class Group(override val id: Long, override val name: String, entries: Node*) extends Node(id, name) {
  override def toString = (id, name).toString + entries.map(_.toString).mkString
}

val tree =
  Group(0, "Root"
    , Group(10, "Shop", Contact(11, "Alice", "312"))
    , Group(20, "Workshop"
      , Group(30, "Tyres", Contact(31, "Bob", "315"), Contact(32, "Greg", "319"))
      , Contact(33, "Mary", "302"))
    , Contact(1, "John", "317"))

println(tree) // (0,Root)(10,Shop)(11,Alice,312)(20,Workshop)(30,Tyres)(31,Bob,315)(32,Greg,319)(33,Mary,302)(1,John,317)
println(tree find {_.id == 32}) //Some((32,Greg,319))
println(tree map {_.name }) //List(Root, Shop, Alice, Workshop, Tyres, Bob, Greg, Mary, John)
```

The good thing is that now you can use of all the benefits of `Traversable[Node]` trait. The problem on the other hand is that I had to override `toString` method in case classes. So I guess there is still room for improvement.

Comment: Thank you [Marek Adamek](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4656533/marek-adamek), I wasn't sure if I need such generic approach but it might be useful for other than lookup tasks so I'll take it :) Amazing that it is so neat.

Comment: You're welcome :) If you don't mind could you give +1 to my answer or maybe ever mark it as solution? I'm trying to earn some reputation here :D

Comment: As soon as I get required reputation(15) I'll vote up for sure.